# filter a column with same value as selected value in slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hello Power BI Community !

I am trying to do something that is supposed to be very simple but I can't manage to do it.

I have a slicer that call a column ('Facts'[Company]) with 5 values (AAPL, MSFT, FB, AMZN, GOOG)

When one of theses values is selected, I want another column ('Facts'[Company Flag], which has same values, to be filtered according to the filtered value.

I think It should be a Dax formula with SelectedValue and Switch/IF, but I am not sure how to do it. can you help me please ?

Maybe like :

MyCustomFilter = IF SelectedValue('Facts'[Company]) = "AAPL";

Filter('Facts'[Company Flag],"AAPL"

right ?

Best regards,

MYPE

Comment: Why do you duplicate a column? Just use the Company column in the slicer and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need DAX for that if you use a slicer. That's the whole point of a slicer. It filters the data according to the selection of the slicer.

If you have a visual that uses a specific column, then you add a slicer on a column of the same table to the report and select a value on the slicer, the visual will only show the data that pertains to that slicer selection.